# How to implement a Macro that can be in a comma operator

Tags: c++, macros

A Macro, say logging something

I want it can be used independently with ";" followed

```
LOG("hello world");
```

and it can appear in a “operator,()”

```
int i = LOG("int"), 42;
```

I tried with do{}while(0),

```
#define LOG(str) do{ cout<<str<<endl; }while(0)
```

but get "expected primary-expression before 'do'

Comment: why use a macro in the first place? Before c++20 I can see a reason, but since `std::source_location` is a thing it has no benefit compared to a function

Comment: Create the lambda, call the lambda.

Comment: Hi @463035818_is_not_an_ai, for a LOG Macro, assembling a string for logging is expensive. If log level is not enough, we could avoid assembling the string. If using log function, string is assembled anyway.

Comment: you can avoid that by lazy streaming along the line of `log() << "int";`. However, thats beyond the scope of the question. I dont want to chime in the all too common "never use macros". Reality is that macros are written sometimes, and this is a valid question and one doesnt need to question your motivation. I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: please do not edit the code in your question after you received an answer. Turning `int i = LOG("int"), 42;` to `int i = (LOG("int"), 42);` would render my answer obsolete, as it is mainly explaining that. I rolled back your edit

Comment: maybe your edit overlapped with the time I had my answer deleted, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is clearly [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why you need LOG macro inside an expression. This is strange unusual requirement and it is a bug prone. Note that there are operators where order of argument evaluation is unspecified so behavior of such log inside expression can have unpredictable outcomes. Can you explain/give an example where this can give some advantages?

Comment: BTW which version of C++ standard you are using? In C++20 this could be solved in nice clean way without macros.

Comment: The obvious way would be for `LOG()` to expand to an expression that gives a value of a (non-`void`) type.   But such a macro would have a lot of gotchas in practice (say, because macros don't honour scope) - there are almost certainly better options than a macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isnt an issue of your macro. You'd also get an error for

```
int i = 42 , 42;
```

[error](https://godbolt.org/z/x5eh7zrWd):

```
<source>:2:17: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
    2 |     int i = 42, 42;
      |                 ^~
```

The grammar doesnt parse this as comma operator. This would be an application of the comma operator:

```
int i = (42, 42);
```

And you can do the same with a macro if you turn it into an immediately invoked lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#define LOG(str) [](){ std::cout<<str<<std::endl; }()
int main() {
    int i = (LOG("int"), 42);
}
```

---

Don't use macros if you can avoid them. For logging a common use case is to use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, but since C++20 there is `std::source_location` that render most uses of logging macros outdated. To avoid construction of strings depending on log levels you can use lazy streaming along the line of `log() << "int" << 42 << "blabla";` (which would only construct the string to be logged when the according log level is set).

---

If you do write macros, you should start by writing the code it should expand to. Make sure it is correct. Then write the macro, with gcc use `-E` to see the code it expands to. In other words, don't think in terms of macros, but in terms of code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the lambda solution is great.
I edit the question to int i = (LOG(xxx), 42);
I use MACRO in LOG to avoid assembling string if log level is not enough like: 
LOG(Info, "string")
LOG(Detail, "avoid assemble this")

Comment: @hczstev as I said, there are ways to avoid constructing the string depending on log level, and no macro is needed for that.

Comment: Lazy streaming only solves half of the problem. If you stream expensive function calls, they'll still be made even if you make `<<` a noop.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat your answer has a solution to this, or wrap the function call into something that only calls the function when needed, eg `log() << "int" << 42 << call_when_piped_to_a_stringstream( expensive_function );`. Details are more hairy of course, but its nothing that can only be solved with a macro.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wouldnt focus too much on the logging. Yes, we know what OP wants to do, also from comments, but the question they did ask would be the same if no logging would be involved. It could be `int i = set_some_global_state("int"), 42;` and the question is about the resulting error

Answer (score 2):

> for a LOG Macro, assembling a string for logging is expensive. If log level is not enough, we could avoid assembling the string. If using log function, string is assembled anyway.

Then the macro should probably look like this: (which among other things makes `LOG` usable as an expression, as you want it o)

```
#define LOG(str) MaybeLog([]{std::cout << str << std::endl;})
```

Where `MaybeLog` is a function that conditionally calls the lambda.

Arguably the output stream should be passed to the lambda as a parameter, and the end of line should be added inside of `MaybeLog`, probably as a `\n` rather than `std::endl`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm filling gaps here, since question doesn't specify desired functionality, but ask fix my solution.

I assume, you which to log when instance of some variable is created.

This could be approached this way:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto logInstaceof(std::string_view txt, T&& x, std::source_location location = std::source_location::current()) -> T
{
    std::cerr << location.file_name() << ':' << location.line() << ' ' << txt << '\n';
    return std::forward<T>(x);
}


int main()
{
    auto i = logInstaceof("int", 33);
    auto j = logInstaceof<int>("int", 23);
    std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
    std::cout << "j = " << j << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hnq8871G8

Now [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) from C++20 is needed only to get location of log. If you do not needed source location, this approach works with any C++ and actually you do not need a macro at all.

Please remember that in C++ macros are evil and [should be avoided](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-macros2) as much as possible. One of the reasons we used macro in C++ was to get source location when printing logs, but this was address by C++20 [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

Note also there are nice ready solution which will work the way you written it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"

int main()
{
    auto i = (spdlog::info("int"), 33);
    std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/P3v5M86bP

Comment: OP also says in the comments that they want to evaluate the argument lazily, only if the logging is enabled. I don't think this is possible without macros, and probably will never be.

Comment: Side note: for me, `std::source_location` is still not usable in portable code. I wished to use it in our code base, but couldn't because as of now (late 2023), latest Xcode toolchain still doesn't support it correctly. And we need Xcode for iOS and macOS builds.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • SpdLog supports macro "evaporation" of the logging at compile time, using a set of macros like `SPDLOG_TRACE("s is {}", expensive_get_s());`.